# with() statement to read from VideoCapture in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, with-statement

I like using a with statement for accessing files and database connections because it automatically tears down the connection for me, in the event of error or file close.

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
for i in f():
   print(i)
f.close()
```

versus

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
   for i in f:
       print(i)
```

Is there an equivalent rephrasing for reading from the camera buffer in the following?:

```
c = cv.VideoCapture(0)    
while(1):
    _,f = c.read()
    cv.imshow('e2',f)
    if cv.waitKey(5)==27:
        cv.waitKey()
        break
c.release()
```

I've tried:

```
c = cv.VideoCapture(0)    
while(1):
   with c.read() as _,f:
       cv.imshow('e2',f)
       if cv.waitKey(5)==27:
           cv.waitKey()
           break
```

---with no luck.  It looks like the tear-down/release is a different kind of function.  Is this idiom possible here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know opencv, so there may be a better answer - but you can always implement the [context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) yourself by defining the `__enter__` and `__exit__` hooks:

```
class MyVideoCapture(cv.VideoCapture):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.release()
```

The usage would then look like:

```
with MyVideoCapture(0) as c:    
    while(True):
        _, f = c.read()
        cv.imshow('e2', f)
        if cv.waitKey(5) == 27:
            cv.waitKey()
            break
```

and the resource will be released after you hit the `break` statement.

Based on your comment, it looks like `opencv` is doing something funky here.  You can also create a custom class to wrap the VideoCapture instance.  In today's world, I'd probably use `contextlib`

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def video_capture_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        vid_stream = VideoCapture(*args, **kwargs)
        yield vid_stream
    finally:
         vid_stream.release()
```

and the usage here would be:

```
with video_capture_wrapper(0) as vid_stream:    
    while(True):
        _, f = vid_stream.read()
        cv.imshow('e2', f)
        if cv.waitKey(5) == 27:
            cv.waitKey()
            break
```

Comment: This looks very much like what I'm looking for.  Sorry, I haven't used context managers before---how exactly would I call this in the context of what I have above?

Comment: @Mittenchops -- Added some sample usage.  In this case, it might also be neat to override `__iter__` to `yield` the data (`f`) as you read it ... But that depends on your actual use case I suppose.

Comment: This definitely looks like what I was thinking of.  I'm getting this error in the class definition though: `  File "./main.py", line 7, in <module>
    class MyVideoCapture(cv.VideoCapture):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    cannot create 'builtin_function_or_method' instances
` but I suspect this'll be enough to get going and tell me what's possible.

Comment: Hmm, played with this some, and seems like it may have deeper problems.

Comment: @Mittenchops -- bummer.  Anyway, I've updated with a solution where we  use composition instead of inheritance.  I don't see any way that could fail ;-)

Comment: Why is the VideoCapture being started in the `__init__` method instead of in `__enter__`? Doesn't that mean that if you construct the class but don't call `__enter__` then there is a leak? Also, even if you construct it in the `with` call, it is then not guaranteed to release if something happens between __init__ and __enter__?

Comment: Even if you put it in `__enter__`, you aren't guaranteed to be leak free if the problem happens between the resource acquisition and the returning from `__enter__` as far as I understand it (though I'd have to read the context management PEP again to be sure of that assertion).  In any case, in today's world, I'd probably recommend using `@contextlib.contextmanager` instead of creating my own class in today's world.

Answer (score 12):

Another way using [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def VideoCapture(*args, **kwargs):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(*args, **kwargs)
    try:
        yield cap
    finally:
        cap.release()
```

(note: the accepted answer has been edited to include this suggestion)

Comment: why yield instead of return?

Comment: Because that's how `context_manager` works. If you use `return` in place of `yield` then `cap.release()` would be called immediately instead of at the end of the `with` statement.