# Python remove file after playing ffpyplayer

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

In my project I like to play a video with cv2 and sound with ffpyplayer.

The code is shown below works except this last line:

```py
os.remove("testinn.mp4")
```

gives an error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'testinn.mp4'.
```

I can conclude that the file has not been properly closed so it can not be deleted. The problem is not at cv2 (it does delete if the ffpyplayer part is deleted). But at ffpyplayer.

How do you close this file so it can be deleted after it has been played?

```py
import os
    
import cv2
import numpy as np
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer

video_name = "testinn.mp4"
window_name = "window"
interframe_wait_ms = 30

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name)
player = MediaPlayer(video_name)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open video.")
    exit()

cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
audio_frame, val = player.get_frame()
while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Reached end of video, exiting.")
        break

    cv2.imshow(window_name, frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(interframe_wait_ms) & 0x7F == ord('~'):
        print("Exit requested.")
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
os.remove("testinn.mp4")
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19086507/7571673

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close `MediaPlayer`.

According to [document](https://matham.github.io/ffpyplayer/player.html#ffpyplayer.player.MediaPlayer.close_player):

> *close_player(self)*
> Closes the player and all resources.

I've used `pathlib.Path.unlink()` to remove file, but should work same with `os.remove`. Check out [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) as this provides convenient and powerful high-level interfaces.

```py
>>> from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> vid = Path("x:/cyan uwu.mp4")
>>> player = MediaPlayer(vid.as_posix())

# Can't delete while MediaPlayer is open

>>> vid.unlink()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1343, in unlink
    self._accessor.unlink(self)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] "<error message in your language>" : 'x:\\cyan uwu.mp4'

# After closing you're free to remove

>>> player.close_player()
>>> vid.unlink()
>>>
```